# C# how to use Unity GameObject as a type constraint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following function:

```
public void FindAndTargetNearestComponentType<TargetType>() where TargetType : GameObject {
        TargetType[] targets = Object.FindObjectsOfType<TargetType>();
        FactionAlignment agentAlignment = this.GetComponentInChildren<FactionAlignment>();
        //find nearest healeragent
        var nearestTarget = targets.Where<GameObject>(target => { // get targets in same faction or ally factions
            FactionAlignment targetAlignment = target.GetComponentInChildren<FactionAlignment>();
            if (
                targetAlignment != null &&
                (
                    targetAlignment.homeFaction == agentAlignment.homeFaction ||
                    targetAlignment.allies.Contains(agentAlignment.homeFaction
                    )
                )
            ) { return true; } else { return false; }
        })
            // sort targets by nearest distance
            .OrderBy(target => Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, target.transform.position))
            .FirstOrDefault(); //pick nearest

        // set destination to target
        this.SetDestination(nearestTarget.transform);
    }
```

This is failing to compile with:

```
 FactionAgent.cs    32  84 error    CS0701 'GameObject' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter. (lsp)
 FactionAgent.cs    33  39 error    CS0314 The type 'TargetType' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Object.FindObjectsOfType<T>()'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TargetType' to 'UnityEngine.Object'. (lsp)
 FactionAgent.cs    36  29 error    CS1929 'TargetType[]' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Where<GameObject>(IEnumerable<GameObject>, Func<GameObject, bool>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<GameObject>'
```

I want this function to accept a generic type that corresponds to a component type. Then query for that component type by passing the generic to `FindObjectsOfType` but seems like `FindObjectsOfType` expects a definition that extends GameObject.

Comment: You say "I want this function to accept a generic type that corresponds to a component type.". If that is the case, you should use `Component` rather than `GameObject` as your constraint.

Comment: @Bart thank you I wasn't aware of that `Component` type. That def improved the situation! however I still have an error that `TargetType[]` doesn't contain a definition of `Where`. I think `Where` is a Linq method and assumed it existed on all array types. But seems not?

Comment: You do not need to specify the type argument, that is inferred from the usage.  `targets.Where(target => ...`  If you want the gameobject, use `target.gameObject` within the where block.